# WCF & Network Bandwidth Throttling

Tags: wcf, networking, throttling, media-channel

I have a client application calling a method of a WCF service. Sometimes one of the parameter of this method call is close to 10MB. This causes a problem when the client is in a really slow network. When the 10MB data is being transferred to the server, other users in the network experience severe slowdown. Is there a way to throttle bandwidth usage per method call?

Searching high and low, only options seems to be writing a custom channel. 
I am not able to find any decent documentation on how to write a custom channel.
Any pointer would really help

Answer (score 1):

I would say your best bet is to look at the infrastructure side. Firewalls or networking appliances, load ballancers.

Answer (score 0):

Set a really small socket send buffer, say 1k. Check the result too, the system may modify what you passed. Set it as low as you can. The objective is to get it smaller than the bandwidth*delay product, so your send can't 'fill the pipe', leaving room for other users.

Comment: Are you referring to the maxbuffersize, maxbufferpoolsize and maxreceivedmessagesize in the binding or some other OS level parameter?

Comment: I am referring to SO_SNDBUF, or in Java Socket.setSendBufferSize().